# Jquery: Cancel button should take you back to the previous Url but if its the first page, take to Default url

Tags: jquery, browser-history, cancel-button

I have a cancel button that should lead me to the previous url of my application.
I have used:

```
if (window.history.length > 0) {
    window.history.back();
}
//If history.back is unsuccesful or no history exists
window.location.href = fallbackUrl;
```

This works ok.
But what i need is that if I am coming from another url like google.com to my current page which has this cancel button(note: this has history), clicking "Cancel" should also call fallbackUrl and not history.back(). How is it possible?

Comment: You mean, you don't want to go back to google.com like this. you want redirection to your own site, right?

Comment: You can check the base url stored in `window.history` and compare it with your website base url if it matches then do redirect otherwise use `fallbackUrl`

Comment: @Kartikeya, window.history doesnt contain any Url.

Comment: @MahaDev, yes exactly

Comment: Ok...Try something like this..modify if statement...`if (window.history.length > 0 && document.referrer.indexOf('websitebaseurl') > -1) {
    window.history.back();
}`

Comment: @Kartikeya, document.referrer is empty

Comment: how about making a **history = []**, array on pageload, every page u visit u can **push** that page name in to that **history array**, if you want get previous page just call **history array length -1**, when u get -1 after calculating the array length -1 that mean ur at the very end, so make **if condition** and call ur  **fallbackUrl**.